# Making A Binary Decision

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to use phrase "Making a binary decision" for the decision which is not well thought out.

> Example: As a president you can not make such a binary decision.

Are there any references for such usage?

Comment: No, that's not what it means. A binary decision is one that forecloses all alternatives; a yes/no decision. Whether it's well thought out or nor is not part of the meaning.

Comment: Having looked in the OED, the meaning of 'binary' might probably extend far enough for you to be technically correct. But I think it would be a confusing remark. The term 'binary' is nowadays so closely identified with the binary arithmetical system and computing, that anyone hearing you would immediately imagine that was what you were talking about.

Comment: @WS2 exactly that's what happened :)

Comment: But I posted before I saw @John Lawler's comment and so far as 'binary decision' is concerned I'm sure he is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not really what [Binary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/binary) means. A "binary decision," though it's not a standard expression would be a decision between two options, such as yes versus no, or red versus white wine.

I think what you mean to say is an "[arbitrary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arbitrary) decision." A decision is "arbitrary" if it is made made without good reason or on a whim.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right that OP has conflated *binary/arbitrary*.

Comment: Agreed. Good call. Answering the question they'd ask if they knew how to -- the basis of all teaching.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is commonly used to indicate that you are choosing between two options and only two options. The example itself is wrong, because a President can indeed decide to make a binary decision. He can, for instance, choose to pardon the turkey at Thanksgiving or not.